# Writing first c program in vi editor in cygwin

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, printf, vi

I [extremely] new to c programming and cygwin so thanks for being patient. I am using a PDF of Michael Vine's C programming for beginners and trying to enter and compile the first example.

Here is what i wrote in vi:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
printf("\nHello World\n");
}
```

When I try to compile using `gcc`, I get two errors:

1) `usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4./... /bin/ld:new: file format not recognized; treating as linked script`

2) `[same path as above]/bin/ld:new:11: syntax error collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

I'm pretty sure the actual syntax I used in vi is correct (its straight out of an example) and the gcc command is also correct. Am I missing a package or is my path to cygwin screwed up? Anyone know what's going on with this?

Comment: Your program is ok, if not strictly correct.  What's the command line you used to build?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Since the problem is that the compiler does not understand its arguments, the problem is likely caused by the compile command you are using. That means you should tell us what the compile command you are using is.  It looks as if you might have `gcc code.c new` or something similar as the command line, and you probably also have a file called `new` in your current directory.

Comment: Yep the filename is "new". I used "gcc new -o new.exe"

Comment: OK - that's your problem.  Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC, for better or for worse, uses the filename you pass to it to figure out what operation to do - run the compiler, the assembler, or the linker, or some combination, for example.  Since you named your source file `new`, GCC is assuming it's a compiled object and is trying to link it.  Either rename it `new.c` or pass the `-x c` flag when compiling.

For future reference, a good way to debug funny business with the GCC compiler driver is to pass the `-v` flag.  If you do so for your original command line you'll see that it just invokes the linker, skipping the compilation step.  An example from my machine:

```
$ gcc -v new -o new.exe
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
 /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/collect2 -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.4 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o new.exe -lcrt1.10.6.o -L/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/x86_64 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/x86_64 -L/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1 -L/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1 -L/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/../../.. -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/../../.. new -lSystem -lgcc -lSystem
ld: warning: ignoring file new, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x20 0x23 0x69 0x6e 0x63 0x6c 0x75 0x64 0x65 0x20 0x3c 0x73 0x74 0x64 0x69 0x6f ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): new
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Thanks Carl! I'm glad it was a common sense issue and not a learning the new language issue lol. Btw, what's your opinion on the need to learn c before learning objective c? Unnecessary or necessary?

Comment: Well, Objective-C is a strict superset of C, so if you learn C, you *are* learning Objective-C in a way.  Getting familiar with some of the "weird" stuff in C is probably helpful to avoid shooting yourself in the foot.  If you can program in some other language already, I'd just go learn Objective-C and the framework you care about directly, rather than making a detour through C first.

Comment: Definitely makes sense; I'll start with Objective C. Thanks again for your help. -Cheers Pete

Answer (score -1):

One basic syntax error:

```
 ' main(){ ... } '
```

In C/C++, your main function should be:

```
'int main(){ ... }'
```